# Inner classes in Scala

Tags: scala

Why this `val aamir =  chatter.Member("abc")` line shows compile time error??

```
package com.aamir.Classes
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer


object Program7 extends App {

val chatter = new Network
val fred = chatter.join("Fred")
val wilma = chatter.join("wilma")
fred.contacts += wilma

val myFace = new Network
val barney = myFace.join("barney")

 val aamir =  chatter.Member("abc")

}

class Network {

    class Member(val name:String) {

    val contacts = new ArrayBuffer[Member]

  }

  private val members = new ArrayBuffer[Member]

  def join(name: String) = {

     val m = new Member(name)
     members += m
     m
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `new`. Alternatively you can make `Member` a case class.

Comment: @m-z val chatter = new Network is already using new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure it should be

`val aamir = new chatter.Member("abc")`,

since Member is a class, not a function

Comment: `val chatter = new Network` already creates chatter so why use new again here and in scala FYI a class can have parameters like methods have in java

Comment: `new Network` creates a network. `new chatter.Member` creates a `chatter.Member`. What's bothering you?

Comment: Compile time error, I tried to create an instance of Member inner class from outside the Network class  `val aamir =  chatter.Member("abc")` line shows Compile time error

Comment: @Aamir Why won't you just try it, instead of trying to argue it? It takes no effort.